# TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable. how to print sql select data without for loop

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, mysql-python

cursor contains single value name=admin so I don't want to use for loop for singe value.anyway possible for the same?

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect("aditi")
con.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGIN
                   (ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    NAME       TEXT NOT NULL,
                    ROLL       INT NOT NULL,
                    PASS       TEXT NOT NULL);''')
quer=f'''INSERT INTO LOGIN(NAME,ROLL,PASS) VALUES('ADMIN','0','ADMIN123')'''
con.execute(quer)
con.commit()

cursor=con.execute('''SELECT NAME FROM LOGIN''')
print(cursor[0])   
con.close()
```

Comment: `print(cursor.fetchall())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cursor.fetchall()[0]` to get the first item returned by your query.